# Is it possible to fill the forms of a pdf using pdftk without breaking Adobe Reader's interaction?

Tags: pdf, pdftk, pdf-form

Consider [this PDF form](https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/i-864.pdf?download=1).

I'd like to fill it using pdftk, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10726664/391161), but preserve the ability to open and edit the form fields in Adobe Reader, as well as preserve the Javascript validation.

Consider the following `fdf` file, which we can put in a file called `Fill.fdf`.

```
%FDF-1.2

1 0 obj
<<
/FDF << /Fields 2 0 R>>
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
[<< /T (form1[0]) /V () >>
<< /T (form1[0].#subform[0].P1_Line1_Name[0]) /V (My Name) >>
]
endobj
trailer
<<
/Root 1 0 R

>>
%%EOF
```

We apply this fdf file to the form using pdftk.

```
pdftk i-864.pdf fill_form Fill.fdf output Output.pdf
```

If we then open `Output.pdf` in Adobe Reader, we get the following error.

> This document enabled extended features in Adobe Acrobat Reader. The
>   document has been changed since it was created and use of extended
>   features is no longer available. Please contact the author for the
>   original version of the document.

I presume that `pdftk` broke Adobe's digital signature when it filled the form, which is what causes the error above.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31428001/391161) removes that error, but it removes the Javascript inside the original PDF, breaking some of the validation on fields that is run when the file is opened in Adobe Reader.

```
pdftk Output.pdf cat output SignatureRemoved.pdf
```

If we open `SignatureRemoved.pdf` in Adobe Reader, we can still edit the form fields, but none of the validation on fields (such as constraining which characters are allowed in each field) runs any longer.

**Is there a way to either remove the signature without removing the Javascript, or reapply the signature to the result of filling a form with pdftk?**

---

Update: I've also attempted to use [qpdf](https://superuser.com/a/850972/109158), but it does not remove the signature.

Comment: You have to fill out the form in *append mode*. This results in PDF's with a higher file size because new data is added after the `%%EOF` marker at the end of the file. The advantage however is that the original bytes are left intact, which preserves the validity of the signature. By the way: pdftk is nothing more than an obsolete version of iText compiled to an executable using GCJ. Please use the original iText, not the copy.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, I seem to be unable to find an executable comparable to `pdftk` on the iText website. Does such an executable exist, or do I have to write my own front end to the iText library to get comparable CLI functionality to `pdftk`?

Comment: You won't find `pdftk` on the iText web site because `pdftk` is not endorsed by iText Group. It uses a version of iText [that shouldn't be used in a commercial context](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, I'm looking for something with a comparable command line interface, not pdftk specifically. does such a front end exist for the modern version of iText?